Альтернатива ЕГЭ по русскому языку: два-три мини-сочинения + грамматический разбор

Два-три мини-сочинения  разного типа (рассуждение, описание, повествование), причем  без лишнего формализма, выявят умение мыслить и правильно излагать свои мысли.
Мини-сочинение лучше пространных рассуждений, там яснее видны все достоинства и недостатки текста: тема, главная мысль, средства связи слов и предложений и т.д.  Тогда и учить школьников будут иначе, то есть действительно русскому языку, а не его подобию.


Также можно добавить сочинение-отзыв о приведенном тексте из литературы. Эта тема есть в современном формате ЕГЭ, но пусть это тоже будет сочинением в свободном стиле (как реальный критический отзыв о произведении).

Обязательная проверка на плагиат, чтобы не было готовых образцов для списывания.

Грамматический разбор трех видов (морфологический,  морфемный,  словообразовательный) по базовой программе.


В качестве "махрового канцеляризма" составителей вопросов на ЕГЭ могу привести недавнее обсуждение Тип речи содержится или представлен? (Это вопрос о рассуждении, которое не то содержится, не то представлено в приведенном отрывке.)
Тогда не надо будет полицейских проверок на входе, но нужно обеспечить отсутствие мобильной связи в аудитории.  Свободная атмосфера для творчества объективность проверки знаний.
Вопрос: Как вы относитесь к такому виду проверки итоговых знаний по русскому языку?
В Рособрнадзоре назвали условие для отмены ЕГЭ
